# extracting variable from one method to another method in the same .m file in objective c, xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hello I would like to know how to use a variable from this method

```
+ (NSString *) yourCalculation:(NSString *)height:(NSString *)weight{
    double bmiVal = 0;
     if (weight > 0 && height > 0) {
         CGFloat wInPounds = [weight floatValue];
         CGFloat hInInches = [height floatValue];
         CGFloat hInCms = hInInches *0.393700787;
    }
}
```

in this method

```
 +(NSString *) actualCalculation{
       float val = wInPounds/(hInCms*hInCms);
       float bmiVal = val *703;
 }
```

This is only a small segment of the code, but it gets across what I want to do with it.

If anyone can tell me how to do this, I would appreciate it.

Thanking You

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Generally you would want to store values like either the `weight` and `height` or the calculated `wInPounds`, `hInInches`, etc. in your data model so you can access them anywhere in your view or calculation code. See [this description of Model, View, Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller) for more information on how and why.

Comment: question is not clear. How can you extract a local variable from another method? Are you trying to get the memory address?

Comment: Don't use the Xcode tag for general iOS programming questions. You don't need Xcode for iOS programming.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom class that has properties for the various values you want to share and return an instance of that.  For example, assuming a `MyNumerics` class with the obvious properties:

```
+ (MyNumerics *) yourCalculation:(NSString *)height weight:(NSString *)weight {
    MyNumerics *result = nil;
    double bmiVal = 0;
    if (weight > 0 && height > 0) {
        result = [[MyNumerics alloc] init];
        result.wInPounds = [weight floatValue];
        result.hInInches = [height floatValue];
        result.hInCms = hInInches *0.393700787;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Have the calling routine use the result's properties in its calculations.

Comment: No, there's no reason for string parameters except that's what the OP had.  There's also no great reason for a class method or two representations of the height but, to illustrate a point, I sometimes think that the fewest changes to the original is the best answer strategy...unless something is outright wrong.  (I try to curb my tendency to rewrite the entire question. :-) )